# ColdFusion Font Management with a non-administrative account

Tags: coldfusion, cfadmin

In the interest of making my ColdFusion 9 server more secure, I recently changed the "Log On" account for the CF Application Service to a non-administrative account. Everything is working fine with one exception: Fonts are no longer available through the "Font Management" tools in CF Administrator. This came up because I use CFDocument to render `.PDF` files and with the non-admin account they went to using only Times New Roman as the font. I've made sure that the service account I created had Full Control rights to the Windows Font directory, and I even copied all the fonts to a non-Windows directory and tried to add them from there. In both cases, the fonts cannot be added using the Font Management tool and do not render in CFDocument. I get no error when attempting to add the fonts - just a blank screen. Only thing I can find in the logs is a reference to `org/jpedal/exception/PDFFontException`.

Anyone out there had experience using a non-admin account to run CF Application Server and what I need to do to get the fonts to work properly?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try giving permission to `\ColdFusion9\wwwroot\CFIDE\administrator\settings` or `\ColdFusion9\wwwroot\CFIDE\administrator\settings\fonts.cfm`?

Comment: as an Adobe support engineer for ColdFusion, you cannot seriously be telling this user that _ColdFusion (all version) should always run under an Administrator Account_ can you? This is one of the first things you learn in order to secure a server - **DO NOT RUN THE SERVICE UNDER AN ADMINISTRATIVE ACCOUNT**. And an account _having privileges equivalent to admin account_ is an administrator account. I had to re-read your post like five times to make sure I was reading it correctly.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that advice directly contradicts the various ColdFusion Lockdown Guides. For security, you give the ColdFusion service account  the *least* amount of access privileges necessary for it to do its job.

Comment: My bad. You are correct Miguel-F and Carl. It was a typo in copy/pasting. I edited my post.

@Michael, can you try the suggestion mentioned.

Comment: Since you removed the bit about running the ColdFusion service as an administrator account I have removed my down-vote.